# Runtime error when class files added to jar in wrong order

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

This is a very strange error that took a while to find out what was going on.  We have multiple jenkins linux slaves that were building a library.  When the library was tested from one slave all was well.  When it was tested with the other it got a runtime error with where it was trying to call a method signature that was non-existent.  After lots of testing, I was able to determine that the order in which the class files were added to the jar determined if the tests would work or not.  Does anyone know where to begin trying to remedy this?  Is this a bug in groovy classloading? java classloading?  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What do you use to build the library? Maven, gradle, something else?

Comment: It's gradle but at this point I've eliminated the original build tool as a possible source of problem by extracting the class files from the good library and using regular zip command to create a bad library by adding them in sorted (produces good) or reverse sorted (produces bad) order.

Comment: are  you including dependencies in your library?

Comment: Nope, it's just the code. Dependencies are packages in the lib folder of the app zip with our lib. I've verified check sums on every file in the app zip as well as the class files in our lib. which is how I found out about the zip ordering because i unzipped to check class files and then retried zipping back up and on my workstation the bad lib started working after zipping it back up. Repeated unzip/rezip of bad lib on server that produced good lib and all was well, repeated test of unzip/rezip on server that produced bad zip and it was still bad!

Comment: Then I noticed the order the files were added to zip (based on stdout) were different between servers. So I did find command piped to sort pipe to zip to have a consistent ordering and I got the bad server to produce a good library. Did a reverse sort pipe to zip and got everyone to be able to produce a lib jar that would have the runtime error.  This is where I'm at now, I don't know how this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the approach that the error state was in fact the correct state and started looking at the application config in detail (I'm on build team, so I was not familiar with this app) and found a bad spring configuration object.  The issue dealt with order in which classes were processed by annotation scanner.  If one class was processed first it would give a bad config which gave a bad app state which caused the error.  The other build servers were building the jar with the bad class later in the config which caused a different state to be loaded which essentially ignored the bad file.  This is why order in which classes were added to the jar mattered.  I was able to correct the bad config and solve the error permanently.